# MassTransit: Setting the default queue type to quorum queues with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We are in the process of updating from using classic mirrored queues to using quorum queues. We are using MassTransit 6.0.0 and I have updated all our calls to ReceiveEndpoint to set the x-queue-type to quorum and all our queues look good and are being created as quorum queues.

However I am worried about some less explicitly created queues being created as classic still. For example _error and _skipped queues.

I also see queues being created by masstransit like 'AU011041_TestQueue_bus_yyyoyynbyybfyfhibdpwqhcqbo' which are still classic.

Is it possible to configure it so all these queues are created as quorum queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the current version of MassTransit, all of those queues can be configured/created as quorum queues. The *_error* and *_skipped* queues are handled automatically, the bus endpoint can be configured the same as a receive endpoint would by adding the queue attribute.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for that. Is there any documentation around configuring the bus endpoint? Also just to clarify, the _error and _skipped queues are handled automatically in the latest version but not 6.0.0? Just want to clarify before I start the migration process

Comment: According to Git history, it was first added in 7.1.8.